# How do i store pdf files into the downloads directory using cordova file, file-transfer and Ionic framework?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, ionic-framework

I do create an Ionic app to open pdf files from urls. It works on android, but unfortunally does not work into windows phone .

if i do open the browser and type an pdf url it works fine and store the pdf into the downloads directory.

My code is here :

http://plnkr.co/edit/SIX6dudoOXc713JWycA3

Thank´s in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now windows phones are not supported by ionic

from ionicframework.com:

`As such, our browser support tends to be whatever Web View API is available to native apps on a given platform. For Ionic 1.1.0 "xenon-xerus", that means UIWebView for iOS 7+, and Android 4.1 and up. Windows Phone and FirefoxOS support is on our roadmap.`

Comment: even using cordova inappbrowser plugin it does not works